# Prosody: Migrate users from old to new domain

Tags: xmpp, ubuntu-12.04

I'm running a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. This server is only accessible within our network. There I was running a Prosody server. When a user registered the user name had following configuration: username@server-ip.

Now, our admins changed a lot in our network and this server got a new IP address and the old address does not exist anymore. The result was that users could not login anymore. After I adjusted all server changes within prosody.cfg.lua there are no users for the new host. Is there a way to change the domain for all users to username@new-server-ip? Or maybe another possibility to import all users?

The last solution would be to have everyone register again, but I would like to avoid that.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Jabbered2/openfire/Tigase. First please check with username@new-server-ip. In case of change in server ip all you need to do is change ip at the time of login   ( with same previous password)

In worst case ( if prosody didn't support it) you still don't need to register all users again ( because that is bad thing to do). In this case you might need to update stuff in you database user table.
Let me know about whether username@new-server-ip works or not?
Thanks

Comment: When I change the IP of my VirtualHost in Prosody according to the database there are no registered users for this host. When I change the host to the old IP (which is not reachable from outside) then I can view all my users. So a login is not possible because the server doesn't know the users. (We also tried to login and it did not work)
I also tried to find out how to access the default prosody database but maybe I have to look further. Until now I couldn't find anything.

Comment: give me some time i will replay back to you